# Stripe gem is not working for create_reversal method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am using [ruby gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) for stripe integration. I am able to create transfer from this gem but when I try to use `create_reversal`.

```
Stripe::Transfer.create_reversal('Xxxxxxxxx')
```

when I use this method I am getting an error like

> NoMethodError: undefined method `create_reversal' for
> Stripe::Transfer:Class

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Couldn't it be an instance method? `Stripe::Transfer.new.create_reversal('Xxxxxxxxx')`

Comment: @bo-oz I am getting this `NoMethodError: undefined method create_reversal for #<Stripe::Transfer:0x3fd20bc0c0d4> JSON: {}`

Comment: which version are you using? There might be a chance of version mismatch

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I am using gem 'stripe', '~> 1.43'

Comment: They are currently at version 4... I'd really advise updating the gem.

Comment: @bo-oz I have upgraded gem with stripe 4.0.1 , when I tried to use this method I am getting `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by upgrading `stripe gem` to the latest version. Once stripe gem is upgraded you also need to upgrade stripe dependencies like `faraday gem` and `oauth2 gem`.follow [link](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/700) for more details about this issue.